# google page rank gives different Result

Tags: c#, pagerank

Hi there
i was checking the list with the software i made to check for page rank.I used proxies to test page rank and surprizingly same list returned different results.

Do page rank depends on proxy Location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> With Keyword "World cup 2011" in
>   google search

[Result for google search in India](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=800&bih=479&q=world%20cup%202011&aq=f&aqi=g2g-z1g1g-z1g5&aql=&oq=)

[Result for google search in UK](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&sugexp=llsfp&xhr=t&q=world+cup+2011&cp=14&pf=p&sclient=psy&site=&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=world+cup+2011&pbx=1&fp=2dbba9f376798118)

In above i searched for keyword "world cup 2011" in google india and google UK
both results list are different so its proved that

> Google results are depend on location. Proxy of another country will provide different result !

hope this will help you!

Comment: +1 Nice to see cricket in answer.. (I'm sure India will win :)

Comment: But do page rank is different i mean stackoverflow has some page rank and would that be different from different proxies?.Search is one thing but page rank is another that does not need to be different

Comment: @Afnan page rank will be a case after country location ! page rank algorithm will not change but it will be in act as per location of proxy !